# What's the most efficient way to write uncertainties of data in a table?

Tags: tables

Let's say that I have two columns of data: one with the values of some measures and the other with its uncertainty. What's the simplest way to join this in a table? I see it's quite difficult to manually write `value $\pm$ uncertainty` in each cell on a `\begin{tabular}` enviroment, so I was wondering if there was another way of doing this.

Comment: In addition to striving for notational efficiency, you should also take into account typographical conventions, which can be highly field-specific. What's common notational practice in one field may be uncommon and confusing in others. Which field do *you* work in?

Answer (score 1):

Another way.  See also siunitx to align decimals.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r@{$\null\pm\null$}l}
3.14 & 0.5
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Try replacing `@{\space$\pm$\space}` with `@{${}\pm{}$}`, though.

Comment: Better.  I had previously tried `\null$\pm$\null` and was not happy.